# how to connect nginx, 3scale and opendaylight controller?

Tags: nginx, opendaylight, 3scale

I am using an Ubuntu machine with an Ubuntu guest OS. On the guest OS, I ran my OpenDaylight controller, making the topologies with Mininet and viewing them in the OpenDaylight GUI at localhost:8080. Next, I used Postman REST API Client extension on my Chrome Browser to make a GET request to my ODL Controller:

localhost:8080/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/

I got the proper response to it in XML format. Now, I have to pass my request through NGINX proxy to 3Scale and get authentication using the app_id and app_key parameters. The request is then to be forwarded to the ODL controller so that I gan get the proper response.

I have already downloaded the proxy config files from NGINX. What modifications must be made in these files? What should be the request I enter in the Postman Client to get the same response as before?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to change the location of the nginx_*.lua file in nginx_*.conf

If you want to change the port that Nginx listens on, you will also need to change the listen directive in the server block, to your desired port e.g

```
server {
  lua_code_cache off;
  listen 81;
```

Also, you will need to ensure that there is an upstream block for your backend, e.g

```
upstream backend_localhost {
  server localhost:8080 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=30;
}
```

but if you have entered this in the proxy configuration wizard that should already be there.

That should be all that you need to change/check.

The request in Postman should target Nginx instead of the ODL Controller, and pass in the application credentials e.g if Nginx is running on port 81

```
localhost:81/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/?app_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&app_key=<YOUR_APP_KEY>
```

Hopefully that should clear up any doubts. However, you can always email us at support@3scale.net if you have any further questions or add any comments here.

Comment: thanks....i tried this now and i am getting an error stating "500 Internal Server Error"....can u help in this regard?